How to add a table of words to stopwords in SQL Server
I have a table of words that want to add to stopwords in SQL  Server. How can I do it?
Am I should add them one by one?
I try by:
insert into sys.fulltext_stopwords (stopword) select stopword from Table_1

but get this error:

Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

I use SQL Server 2022.

try:
-- Add stopwords to the custom stoplist
DECLARE @stopword NVARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE stopword_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT stopword FROM Table_1;

OPEN stopword_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM stopword_cursor INTO @stopword;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Construct the dynamic SQL statement
    SET @sql = N'ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST CustomStoplist ADD ''' + @stopword + N''' LANGUAGE 0;';
    
    -- Execute the dynamic SQL statement
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM stopword_cursor INTO @stopword;
END

CLOSE stopword_cursor;
DEALLOCATE stopword_cursor;


make sure that Table_1 exists and contains the stopwords you want to add
make sure to replace YourTableName, YourColumnName, and YourPrimaryKeyIndex with the actual names of your table, column, and primary key index.


Thank you for your help. But I get that error again! I check the stopwords with select * from sys.fulltext_stopwords and see that @stopword is added to it, not fields of table!
